# Hide invalid methods in Django Rest Framework Documentation View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, core-api

If a set of methods, e.g. for creation, deletion, and update are only available for admin users, I want to be able to hide the method in the documentation view, but I have found no way to do so. Is this possible?

```
class MyDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Comment: You can't ***hide the methods***, but can restrict the actions by specifying *permission_classes*

Comment: Yes, this is what I do, but i wanted the method availability given permission classes to be reflected in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just hide the method in the default documentation view.
You can do this on your front end, but the documentation view has no such functionality. It's just there to show the endpoints and the requests allowed on them.

User permissions are something that you will check and then render the appropriate forms in your front end.

Comment: That's a pity. I had hoped that the front end would have been smart enough to look at the permission classes and current user, then decide if it should show the create tab for example or not.

Comment: Well, maybe that's possible through django's admin panel with the use of forms, but haven't tried it because I have never used it in production, I always rely on a custom front-end client.